# visual studio code filter search results by filename

Tags: visual-studio-code, search

I'm searching for specific phrase in visual studio code:
[image: search bar]
However, I'm getting to many results and would really like to filter for files with a very specific phrase in their name.
Is there any easy way to do so?

Comment: files to include: `*PHRASE*.cs` (where `PHRASE` is your specific..., and `.cs` file suffix;) !? also possible: `some/path/*PHRASE*.suffix`

Comment: @xerx593 tried that with no luck :(

Comment: As @xerx593 said, `*{i,I}ndex*.cs`   seems to work for me.  It is case-sensitive, the `{i,I}` works as an alternative casing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark suggested I needed to write it in the following format, as its case sensitive:

```
*{i,I}ndex*.cs
```